# (SOLVED) UV Unwrapping does not work properly

Tags: uv, edit-mode

So, i think many of you have been at the point of watching Blenderguru's beginner tutorial.
I am currently at Part 5, Level 3 where you need to UV unwrap your cup. There are two problems, the first being, that my UV map is not showing up properly as it should (see Screenshot). The second problem is, that after I created the first seam, it literally made a seam into my object and I dont know how to correct it.[image: so this is the unwrapped cup]
[image: and this is the seam, that appeared right after I've done the UV seam. this is also visible in Viewport Render]

Comment: Hello, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/Sqpv295b here it is

Comment: first thing, you have floating edges, i.e. edges that are not associated with faces, that are overlapping with other edges, you can see it if you hide the faces. So select all and press Alt M to Merge by Distance. Also, apply the scale in Object mode. For your unwrap, it all depends how you want to unwrap, for this kind of object, as it has a handle, maybe mark some seams, then U to unwrap

Comment: what exactly do you mean with "applying Scale in object mode"?

Comment: once in object mode, select the object and press Ctrl A > Apply Scale

Comment: apply scale is already checked. When i hide the faces right along the Seam, i still can see a vertex being connected at the top

Comment: also, i tried select similar and select loose geometry, nothing of that has helped

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, to get rid of the floating edges, I think a simple Alt M > Merge by Distance should work (it will merge the overlapping vertices)

Comment: also, you want to unwrap your cup, the unwrap method will depend on what you want to do, if you just want to paint on your cup in the 3D view, you can unwrap with the Smart UV Project method. If you don't want to project any image texture on your cup, you don't even need to unwrap.

Comment: i cant find the floating edges, it somehow tells me there arent any. or do i need to find them in a specific way?

Comment: please see my answer, I hope it's clear

Answer (score 1):

As you can see if I select these faces and hide, I can see some "floating" edge loops here, they are creating these artifacts we see. You could delete them manually but if you select all and merge the vertices (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>) you will probably get rid of them:

[image]

As for the unwrap, the method you need to use depends on what you want to do, if you don't plan to use an *Image Texture* you don't even need to unwrap actually. If you want to paint on your object in the 3D view, you can simply unwrap with the *Smart UV Project* option. If you plan to use an already made image and you need to make the UV match, mark some seams on you topology then unwrap with the *Unwrap* option.

Answer (score 0):

I now deleted all those floating edges by first hiding the faces and then through X>Vertices removed them. thats what happened after.

E: now did it with just merging them. it still shows me, that i have some floating, but they dont interfere and the seam is gone. And now the Unwrap works properly, so thanks for the help[image]